# xcode 8 console area doesn't show anything

Tags: ios, xcode8

**I was trying to run my app but my console area doesn't show anything**

*I tried many solution but I can't fix that*

**any help please ??**

Comment: Please create a [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit it into your question

Comment: am working on an iPhone/iPad app. All of a sudden output console stopped displaying ANY messages AT ALL. I tried to open older project - works just fine. So I thought that local project's repository got corrupted somehow, so I tried to create a new project - no messages at all are getting written to console output. Did I do something with Xcode settings accidentally? I am at a complete loss and frustrated.

Please help if you have any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the console and not the variable view?

Comment: my app is running but nothing appears on my console log

Comment: Can you add a screenshot

Comment: https://ibb.co/dcwjdF

Comment: Make sure the program is running on debug configuration instead of release configuration.  You can verify by going to Xcode -- > Product Menu --> Scheme --- > Edit Scheme

Comment: yes it's on debug configuration

Answer (score 1):

I think you've deactivated your console by mistake, try pressing: *shift-command-c*

Alternatively, you can do that by going to:

> View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console.

Comment: I did that but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

To open console

```
command+shift+y
```